# mongoengine default timeout configuration

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a django project running on top of MongoDB via mongoengine. 
After I got inconsistent results for list querysets (object.filter() etc.) I've set the queryset to run without a timeout - by calling queryset.timeout(False) - and that seemed to solve the issue.
My questions are:
1. What is the default timeout settings for mongoengine?
2. Is there a way to control the timeout configuration for mongoengine?

Comment: @DrutaRuslan this comment, without any explanation, is not useful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The default timeout isn't set by mongoengine so it falls back to the mongodb cursor timeout which is 10 minutes (see [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-behaviors))
2. There is no specific support for it in mongoengine but mongodb seems to offer that feature with the `cursorTimeoutMillis` parameter (see [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.cursorTimeoutMillis)).